# Converting any web page content to UTF-8 using http4

Tags: http, utf-8, apache-camel

I am using apache camel-http4 .

I want to convert any web page content to UTF-8, I am using http4 as my httpClient.

I have created my HttpClientConfigurer class that implements org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpClientConfigurer.

I have set HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET to Consts.UTF_8, like this in configureHttpClient method.

```
   public void configureHttpClient(HttpClient client) {
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1).setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET,Consts.UTF_8);
}
```

But this didn't seems to work.

I have also tried to set header to UTF-8 like this,

```
  setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING, constant('UTF-8'))
```

inside my route but that too didn't work.

Any idea on how to convert any page encoding to UTF-8 using http4.

Comment: Camel's [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/http4.html) mentions setting it on Exchange : exchange.setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, Encoding magic don't work that easy like this. It hardly depends on your input charset and your message body has to be in right encoding to convert it properly to the output. So, you have to

1. receive input in proper encoding **(if not it will do not work)**
2. covert the body to utf-8 encoding. Via `.convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")` (if 1. is wrong it will not work)
3. send it out with proper encoding metadata, which you did `Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING`